# How can I restrict a for-loop pattern to stay within a shape? Basically, how can I fill a shape with a pattern instead of a color?

Tags: for-loop, processing, shapes

I am trying to create concentric circles filled with lines moving in opposite directions (that follow the mouse). I can't figure out how to fill only the circles with the lines -- I used a for-loop to make lines, and want to cut them off outside of the radius of the circles. Basically, I am trying to fill the circles with a pattern of lines.

This is my code:

```
float r = 0;

float startAngle;

float density;

float radius;

void setup() { 

  size(500, 500);

  background(255);

  stroke(150, 0, 150);

} 

void draw() {

  int[] s = {

    500, 325, 200, 100, 50, 25

  };

   for (int i = 0; i < 500; i = i+5) {

     line(0, i, 500, i);

     if(i > s[0]) {

       noStroke(); 

     }

  }

  translate(width/2, height/2);

  rotate(r);

  r = r + .01; 

  fill(0); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[0], s[0]);

  fill(50); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[1], s[1]);

  fill(100); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[2], s[2]);

  fill(150); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[3], s[3]);

  fill(200); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[4], s[4]);

  fill(255); 

  ellipse(0, 0, s[5], s[5]); 

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

The best advice I can give you is to start smaller. [Break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time.

For example, instead of starting with your whole program that shows multiple circles, why not start with a simpler example program that just shows a single circle? Try to get a pattern to display inside of that.

Like everything in programming, there are multiple ways to do that.

**Option 1:** You could probbaly use basic geometry and trig to figure out where the points should be on the circle, then draw them based on those points. The `cos()` and `sin()` functions would probably come in handy with this approach.

**Option 2:** You could also use image masking techniques. For example, you could create a texture of lines, and then use a circular mask to isolate a cirlce of those lines. The `texture()` function or the `PImage#mask()` functions would be your friends here.

Try out those approaches to see which one you like best. [The Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/) is your best friend: for example, [here](https://processing.org/reference/texture_.html) is a reference on the `texture()` function, and [here](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html) is a reference on the `PImage#mask()` function. Then if you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of just that step, and we'll go from there. Good luck.